# Error: "Currently no logon servers available" while connected via crossover and using built-in Admin

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, network-share

A "client" system and a "server" system are connected via crossover cable.  The "client" is running Windows Server 2003, and the "server" is running Windows XP Pro SP3.

The client and server ping fine both ways.  When I try accessing file shares (i.e.: C$) on the client system, using the server, it works fine.  My problem is that when I use the client to access files on the server, I get a "no logon servers available" error.

I'm logged on to each system using local accounts.  This error generally occurs without prompting me for any credentials, but also will happen after credentials have been provided.

I've Googled this thing to death, and nothing's worked so far.  What's most baffling is that it's happening at all, when I'm trying to use *local accounts* to connect.  What could I be missing here?

Comment: Are you connecting via IP or via hostname? Also, if you have GbE cards on both ends, you don't need a crossover cable.

Comment: @MDMarra Using IP address or hostname, it behaves the same.  And, I am actually using a straight cable.  I just wanted to make it fully clear that it's a direct PC-to-PC connection.

Comment: Is either system a domain member?

Comment: @wfaulk Both systems are members of a domain - whether it's the same domain or not, at this point, I'm not sure yet.  Again, though, we are operating offline from the domain and trying to use local accounts to authenticate.

Comment: Care to open `sysdm.cpl` and check the name of the domain that each system is joined to?

Comment: @MilesErickson I'll be doing that next time I'm on-site.  I have very strong suspicions that they're not with the same domain though.  Still, I don't see the relevance.  (Then again, it seems like just about anything could be the root cause now - since I haven't yet figured out what is.)

Comment: @MilesErickson They're members of different domains.  The domain the server is assigned to doesn't even exist any more, but changing domain membership status is not something I can do for the purposes of resolving this issue.

Comment: OK, it's time to take a step back. What is the actual purpose of this exercise? Is the client simply asking to recover certain files from the server due to inadequate backups? Is someone proposing to leave these computers connected together in this way indefinitely? Is it really not okay to remove the server from the old domain that no longer exists?

Comment: Just FYI to future answers: "Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options -> Interactive Logon: Require Domain Controller authentication to unlock" is disabled for these machines

Comment: @MilesErickson At this point, it is not authorized to remove the server from the old domain.  The client device requires access to the C$ in order to analyze the installed software and configuration of the system.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a problem that we can "work around".  We need to get the client to be able to see C$.  There is no other option, to fill the needs of this exercise.

Comment: Good news.  We actually *did* (surprisingly) get authorization to remove the device from the domain.  It's bittersweet though - I would have been very interested to find a different solution.

Comment: @Iszi ...to analyze the installed software and configuration? Is this a forensic exercise?

Comment: @MilesErickson Close - vulnerability assessment.

Comment: What tool is this? I need to be sure I never use or recommend it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up resolving the issue by removing the server from the defunct domain.  Once it was in "workgroup" configuration, the shared folders behaved normally.

Comment: Could you mark this as an answer mate?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to see the configuration of the server, do that using WMI. Checking individual files on a running system via CIFS is Not Correct.

Unfortunately, we don't always have access to the correct way. If the tool you're using needs access to the filesystem, you can share the filesystem in other ways, including NFS, SFTP, etc.

Comment: This is not an option.  The tool we use is not one which we can alter in a way that would circumvent this problem.  And, it is *required* that we use this specific tool.